# MSI installed add-in for all terminal server users, how do I configure it just for one user?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, windows-installer, invantive-control, terminal-server

A MSI I have installed for an Excel add-in (Invantive Control), installed the add-in for all users. I am running on terminal server, so now all users have this add-in, while it is only used by one single user. I had like just this single to user to use the add-in.

How do I configure the add-in to work only for this one user?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning! This answer provides a solution that involves changing the registry. Please make sure you have a valid backup in case you might break anything.**

First, you need to export the current state of the add-in installation. You can do that by exporting the following registry key using the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`). Then you have to run a slightly altered version on the user account. Here is how you will do that:

1. Click the Windows icon and type `regedit.exe`. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Invantive Control for Excel`, and export that key using the `File` menu. Save the file on your desktop.
2. Change the value of the `LoadBehavior` key to `0`. This will disable the add-in for all users.
3. Open the file you just saved. Change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Distribute this file to the user that needs to have the add-in enabled.
4. Log in as the user that needs to have the add-in enabled. From that user account, run the registry file you have edited in the previous step.
5. The add-in should load for this user, and not for others.

For completeness, these are the registry as used for the installation on my machine. Your configuration might differ, for example on the file paths. Use with care.

The registry except to disable the add-in for all users:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Invantive Control for Excel]
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000000
```

The registry except to enable the add-in for the current user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\Invantive Control for Excel]
"Description"="Invantive Control for Excel"
"FriendlyName"="Invantive® Control for Excel"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"Manifest"="file:///C:/Program Files/Invantive Software B.V/Invantive Control for Excel/Invantive.Producer.Control.vsto|vstolocal"
```